# Dynamic mapping of all *.test domains for Homestead

Tags: laravel, nginx, homestead

I'm using *dnsmasq* to access all `*.test` domains locally. Now, I'd like to make Homestead box automatically point each domain to appropriate project. So if I go to `foo.test`, it would open the project at `/foo.test/public` directory. It's very convenient, as my machine doesn't need to be provisioned for new projects. I used to have it working by setting up in Homestead.yaml:

```
- map: '~^(?<project>.+\.test)$'
  to: /home/vagrant/code/$project/public
```

However, a few versions ago it stopped working, giving the following error:

> ==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
>   homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Certificate: ~^(?.+.test)$
>   The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
>   assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
>   should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
>   went wrong.

There is a commit that gives some hope: [Self-Signed Wildcard Certificates](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/commit/829c857fb93c3377772087ec12547dace11c052b).

Is it currently possible to set up Homestead like I'm trying to?